# If-then-else statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to score customers from the logistic regression I did.  After calculating their probabilities, I have created a data frame with these variables:
CUSTID, depvar, prob
Next, I was able to get the deciles of the probabilities.

```
> quantile(prob, p=seq(0, 1, length=11), type=5)
       0%       10%       20%       30%       40%       50%       60%       70%       80%       90%      100% 
0.0373546 0.1990744 0.2961668 0.3748728 0.4393759 0.4970248 0.5554679 0.6162423 0.6905081 0.8007684 0.9999996
```

Finally, I want to attach the decile to the end of the data frame.  Here is my code:

```
> #Chained if-then-else
> if (prob <=.1990744) {decile<-10} else if (prob >.1990744) {decile<-9} else if (prob >.2961668){decile<-8} else {if (prob >.3748728) {decile<-7} else if(prob >.4393759) {decile<-6} else if (prob >.4970248){decile<-5} else {if (prob >.5554679) {decile<-4} else if(prob >.6162423) {decile<-3} else if (prob >.6905081){decile<-2} else {if (prob >.8007684) {decile<-1} else {decile=0}
+
```

As you see, I'm left with a + sign as if R is expecting me to type something else.  How should I construct this if-then-else statement?

Thanks.

Comment: The `+` is the result of mismatched parentheses. Anyway, you cannot use `if` and `else` here. You could use a nested `ifelse` which is vectorized, but you should use `cut` or `findInterval`.

Comment: To complete @Roland comment, after reformatting your code, you have two places where there's a `{` between a `else` and a `if`, search for `else {if`. Try using a script for long statements like this and indent inner statements, it really helps figuring when something doesn't close properly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `if` and `else` here. You can use `cut` to label categories.

First some example data since you didn't provide a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(prob = rnorm(100))
```

Calculate deciles:

```
quant <- quantile(dat$prob, probs = seq(0, 1, length.out = 11), type = 5)
```

Use `cut` to label the continuous values with respect to the deciles:

```
dat2 <- transform(dat, decile = cut(prob, c(-Inf, quant), labels = 0:10))

head(dat2)    
#         prob decile
# 1 -0.6264538      2
# 2  0.1836433      6
# 3 -0.8356286      2
# 4  1.5952808     10
# 5  0.3295078      6
# 6 -0.8204684      2
```

Comment: I needed an additional close parenthesis at the end.  I got a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the explanation of why it doesn't work:

```
if (prob <=.1990744) {
  decile<-10
} else if (prob >.1990744) {
  decile<-9
} else if (prob >.2961668) {
  decile<-8
} else { # Here
  if (prob >.3748728) {
    decile<-7
  } else if(prob >.4393759) {
    decile<-6
  } else if (prob >.4970248) {
    decile<-5
  } else {
    if (prob >.5554679) {
      decile<-4
    } else if(prob >.6162423) {
      decile<-3
    } else if (prob >.6905081) {
      decile<-2 
    } else { # and there
      if (prob >.8007684) {
        decile<-1
      } else {
        decile=0
      }
```

You can see there's two places where you have an opening bracket. Either remove them, or add 2 at the end of code to fix it.

Really, use `cut` as shown by @Sven, this answer is just to showcase why formatting your code would help you finding problems.

Comment: I agree, I hadn't used the cut statement before.  It helped.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This an answer using ifelse, first make dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(prob = rnorm(10, mean= 0.5, sd = 0.3), decile = NA)
```

then this:

```
attach(df) 

df$decile <-ifelse(prob <=.1990744, 10, 
        ifelse(prob <.2961668, 9,
        ifelse(prob <.3748728, 8,
        ifelse(prob <.4393759, 7,
        ifelse(prob <.4970248, 6,
        ifelse(prob <.5554679, 5,
        ifelse(prob <.6162423, 4,
        ifelse(prob <.6905081, 3,
        ifelse(prob <.8007684, 2, 
        ifelse(prob <.9999996, 1, 0))))))))))

detach(df)
```

Comment: The use of `attach` and `detach` will make your life very hard in large codebases. Furthermore, the use of so many nested `ifelse` statements is not needed as you can use `cut`.

Comment: If I ever have a case where I only have 1 or 2 if-then-else, I'll use this as my reference.  Thanks.

Comment: It is unclear to me @WillCoop4 why you flag this solution as the best solution. The obvious pick is the `cut` answer of Sven.

Comment: You're right. I wanted to acknowledge you for answering another common thing I'll need to start doing, where your solution would work better.